# Stop music on mouse out

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events

I have a movieclip which has this script attached to it (plays a soundclip on hover) - problem is that if I move the mouse out I need to stop the soundclip. Right now it just starts again while its still playing (on mouse over) == not good.

Does anyone have a solution? I tried to make a `MOUSE_OUT` event and a `.stop();` but it does not seem to work. Thank you!

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

//Declare a BeepSnd sound object that loads a library sound.
var BeepSnd:BeepSound = new BeepSound();
var soundControl:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel(); 

somebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,playNoises);
somebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,stopNoises);

function playNoises(event:Event){
    playSound(BeepSnd);
}

function playSound(soundObject:Object) {
    var channel:SoundChannel = soundObject.play();
}

function stopNoises(event:Event){
    stopSound(BeepSnd);
}

function stopSound(soundObject:Object) {
    var channel:SoundChannel = soundObject.stop();
}
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
at radio_fla::MainTimeline/stopSound()
at radio_fla::MainTimeline/stopNoises()
```

Comment: Could you post the entire code? where do you stop the sound?

Comment: This is the entire code - there is no where I stop it. I need to incorporate this. :-)

Comment: You said you tried to add a `MOUSE_OUT` event and a `.stop();`, if you post that code maybe someone can tell you why it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the `SoundChannel` created when playing a `Sound`. A `Sound` represents a sound, while a `SoundChannel` represents the *playback* of a sound, and it is the playback, that you want to stop.

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

//Declare a BeepSnd sound object that loads a library sound.
var BeepSnd:BeepSound = new BeepSound();
var soundControl:SoundChannel;

somebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,playNoises);
somebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,stopNoises);

function playNoises(event:Event){
    playSound(BeepSnd);
}

function playSound(soundObject:Object) {
    soundControl = soundObject.play();
}

function stopNoises(event:Event){
    stopSound();
}

function stopSound() {
    if (soundControl) {
        soundControl.stop();
        soundControl = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is that you actually have to call the stop method on the channel object, not on the sound object: `channel.stop()`. Also you may consider using `ROLL_OVER/OUT` instead of `MOUSE_OVER/OUT`, but this has nothing to do with your problem of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try using MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER AND MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT instead of MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT.